# Why are V-Ray asset library textures pink when loaded into Blender?

Tags: texturing

I am not trying to reuse the .mat shaders, just the .tx textures that come with V-Ray's asset library. I tried loading them in Clarisse, and it worked. But in Blender they are pink. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Pink color means missing textures. May be Blender don't associate them. Try to browse the textures manually in the Shader Editor if the texture files available in file browser.

Comment: No, it says it can't load the image when I try loading it in Texture Properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, support for textures caches as .tx is planned but not done yet, see:
[T68917: Cycles: texture cache and mipmaps](https://developer.blender.org/T68917)